# Blank page getting displayed when we have a language version of an item other than English

Tags: sitecore-client

We have a multi-lingual site, where for some pages we only need the version in a specific language ( e.g. JA) version but not English.  When we try to create only JA version of an item and try to visit the page, we are able to view the page, when we try to view the page in English, we are getting a blank page, where it should be redirected to page not found.

I have tried this on a blank sitecore 10 instance and was able to reproduce the same.

- Copy Home page
- Create a Language version(JA)
- Delete the English version.
- I can see the below blank page.
  [image]

Has anyone faced similar issue and found a solution?

Comment: This behaviour is by design. You would need to 404 this yourself.

Comment: We have implemented custom 404, but the context item "Sitecore.Context.Item" is not null when this item is getting viewed in English languiage - for which we do not have any version in content Editor. Could you provide any suggestions ?

Comment: Context.Item would never be null in default behaviour. You need to check whether it has a version in the language you are requesting. Context.Item.Versions.Count > 0 or something similar.